# Retain Form Data Entered When clicking back button of a browser after autocomplete ajax call

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, forms, retain

I have an aspx form where the user enters an employee name in an input box.  Performing an ajax call to dynamically search for a list of in the employee table where the user can select a name.

At the bottom of the form there is a "Continue" button to advance to next page within same aspx.

Everything works fine until continue button is pressed and can see the entered values in the next page.

When clicking the browser back button all the values entered in all input fields (Both using autocomplete / plain entry) is lost.

The back button is enabled to make modification to one or two entered values, but the form should not clear all the values entered.

Is there anyway to retain the values entered on hitting back button in a browser ?

Btw, the back button works fine without Ajax/Autocomplete.

Thanks in advance.
Elan

employee.aspx and employee.aspx.cs given below.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".txtSearchEmployee").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                var objbData={
                    formFieldId:$(this)[0].element[0].id,
                    prefix:request.term 
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "employee.aspx/GetEmployeeName",
                    data: JSON.stringify(objbData),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Not Found.  Please search again.");
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2
        });
    </script>

[WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetEmployeeName(string formFieldId, string prefix)
    {
        List<string> employees = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
               cmd.CommandText = "select vldf2 + ' ' + vldf3 as fullname from employees where vldf2 like '%" + prefix + "%' Or vldf3 like  '%" + prefix + "%'";
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    employees.Add(dr["fullname"].ToString());
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        return employees.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: When the continue button is clicked, do you store the data in any way before advancing to the next page?

Comment: Yes, that's one way I can put back the values.  However, I wonder if there is any possibility with browser-back button clicked.  Without the Ajax Call, it retains the data, perfectly fine.

Comment: Is there any possibility to alter the Jquery file code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js that clears the input field on page-load ?